# Error while running test case

Tags: python

I need to test my code below. I am using one test to see if it is working or not. but dont know what exactly I should pass as a parameter in the test code. Please see the test code at the end and please guide me what value I should pass here? Because whatever I write here, it throws me an error.

```
from brisa.core.reactors import install_default_reactor
reactor = install_default_reactor()


import os
import unittest

from brisa.upnp.device import Device, Service
from brisa.upnp.device.service import StateVariable


class SwitchPower(Service):

    def __init__(self):
        Service.__init__(self,
                         'SwitchPower',
                         'urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1',
                         '',
                         os.getcwd() + '/SwitchPower-scpd.xml')
        self.target = False
        self.status = False


    def SetTarget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target = kwargs['NewTargetValue']
        self.status = self.target
        self.set_state_variable('Status', self.target)
        print 'Light switched ', {'1': 'on', '0': 'off'}.get(self.target, None)
        return {}

    def GetTarget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'RetTargetValue': self.target}

    def soap_GetStatus(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'ResultStatus': self.status}


class BinaryLight(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_name = 'Binary Light device'
        self.device = None
    def _create_device(self):
        project_page = 'https://garage.maemo.org/projects/brisa'
        self.device = Device('urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1',
                            self.server_name,
                            manufacturer = 'Ankit',
                            model_name = 'Binary Light Device',
                            model_description = 'Test Device',
                            model_number = '1.0',
                            model_url=project_page)
    def _add_service(self):
        switch = SwitchPower()
        self.device.add_service(switch)
    def start(self):
        self._create_device()
        self._add_services()
        self.device.start()
        reactor.add_after_stop_func(self.device.stop)
        reactor.main()


# Here's our "unit tests".

class IsOddTests(unittest.TestCase):



    def testOne(self):

        self.failUnless(_create_device('urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
         unittest.main()      



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        device = BinaryLight()
        device.start()   


Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

The Error is:-

```
ERROR: testOne (__main__.IsOddTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binary_light.py", line 67, in testOne
    self.failUnless(_create_device('urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'))
NameError: global name '_create_device' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Probably because the Error was not immediately visible.

Answer (score 1):

In your `testOne()` method, you're calling `_create_device()`, which isn't a global function it's a method on SwitchPower objects.

You probably want to create a new SwitchPower object.

Comment: Basically, when I execute this file, it executes successfully but dopesnot generate any output. To generate the output, I need to write the test cases. Could you guide me in doing this?If you post the answer here with the changes, that will be more useful to me.Same is the case with binary light. If I wnat to test its function, what should I do.? please help me with code.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not really a "write the code for me" kind of site -- it's really for getting answers to specific programming questions.  Also, if this happens to be homework, you might read:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: it is not a hw. I am very much assure what I am doing here. Its for my practice and want to know about Python Brisa Framework.Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

`_create_device()` is not defined in class `IsOddTests`.  It is defined in `BinaryLight`.

I'm not completely sure about this, but what about changing:

> self.failUnless(_create_device('urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'))

to:

```
bl = BinaryLight()
self.failUnless(bl._create_device())
```

I removed:

> 'urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'

because it was in the definition of `_create_device()`.

Comment: yes...the IsOddtests is a test case for me.Basically, when I execute this file, it executes successfully but dopesnot generate any output. To generate the output, I need to write the test cases. Could you guide me in doing this?If you post the answer here with the changes, that will be more useful to me.Same is the case with binary light. If I wnat to test its function, what should I do.? please help me with code.

Comment: _create_device() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) - this is the error now.